# How to save an option title and values for a specific store view?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I'm trying to create a product programmatically in Magento 1.8 and then add some customs options to it. So far everything is working, all of the options are being saved correctly with the product under the "default" scope.

The problem is that my store has two different "store view", one in English and one in French. I can't figure how to set the scope on the option.

When I set the scope on the product I can't seem to be able to fetch the already added options on the default. Keep in mind I do not want to set different options for each store view, I just want to translate some fields.

Here's a code sample :

```php
     $option = array(
            'title' => 'Option title', // this needs to be translated per store view
            'type' => 'radio',
            'is_require' => 1,
            'sort_order' => 6,
            'values' => array(
                array(
                    'title' => 'Value 1', // this needs to be translated per store view
                    'price' => 0,
                    'price_type' => 'fixed',
                    'sku' => '',
                    'sort_order' => '1'
                ),
                array(
                    'title' => 'Value 2', // this needs to be translated per store view
                    'price' => 0,
                    'price_type' => 'fixed',
                    'sku' => '',
                    'sort_order' => '2'
                )
            )
        );
```

Comment: So far I have been able to fix the problem by using straight db queries to translate the options but this is really a ugly fix and I'm pretty sure there is a better way builtin magento to address this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an example you can try below:

```
//Create options array
$values = array(
 //15 is the option_id of the option in 'eav_attribute_option_value' table
 15 => array(
   0 => 'Apple' //0 is current store id, Apple is the new label for the option
  ),
 19 => array(
   0 => 'Nexus'
  ),
 12 => array(
   0 => 'HTC'
  ),
);
```

Clear translation cache because attribute labels are stored in translation

```
 Mage::app()->cleanCache(array(Mage_Core_Model_Translate::CACHE_TAG));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to modify options saving product, you should not only set store id to product, but also add an **'option_id' key** to **$option array** to identify that you are saving the same option.

If you'd like to work with options, it would be a good idea to take a look on Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::saveOptions() method.

Here is an example of code that allows you to save a custom option with translation:

```
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option $option */
$option->setData($optionData)
    ->setData('product_id', $productId)
    ->setData('store_id', $firstStoreId)
    ->save();
$optionData['title'] = $translatedTitle;
$option->setData($optionData)
    ->setData('product_id', $productId)
    ->setData('store_id', $secondStoreId)
    ->save();
```

Answer (score -1):

You just have to go in **Catalog** -> **Attributes** -> **Manage Attributes**. After click on your Attribute and go to **Manage label/Options**.

You can here set a translation / store.

Comment: I want to do it programmatically.